# how copy drawable in android?

Tags: java, android

hi i would like copy a drawable in a file with android. My problems are my image file are completely black. I don't know why.

```
    try{
    Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header);
    Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( image.getMinimumWidth(), image.getMinimumHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);  
        File fs = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/file/header.png");                                   
        FileOutputStream fos;
        fos = new FileOutputStream(fs);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        image.draw(canvas);
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, fos); 
        //refermer
        fos.flush();
        fos.close(); 
        } catch (IOException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It is probably because you are not following the measure-layout-draw routine when drawing on a custom canvas. Your view has not been measured and has not been laid out yet, and that's why you see a black screen.

In other words, call a measure on the image (or set its desired measured width and measured height) first. This can be achieved by calling measure(int,int) on the image view or calling image.setMeasuredWidth(int) and image.setMeasuredHeight(int).

After that, you must lay out your view - call image.layout(int,int,int,int). After that, when using image.draw(canvas), you should be able to see it on your bitmap.

Further reading here:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/how-android-draws.html

Comment: integrer drawable pdf
sorry, I forgot to put this part of the code. I define the size of the image precisely      
        Drawable image = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.header);
    Bitmap  bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap( image.getMinimumWidth(), image.getMinimumHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);